# Disabling Transaction Management in Spring JMS listener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

I have a spring boot application as a Spring JMS listener. i have configured multiple datasource manager one for Oracle and another one for DB2 .

whenever i am starting app ,jms listener container is looking for a transaction manager bean and giving below error as it find two bean.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.transactionManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: db2TransactionManager,oracleTransactionManager
```

i dont want to maintain JMS transaction. how could i achieve it or how can we disable jms transaction feature?

below are the annotation i have added on my main spring boot class. also i am using Spring Data repository

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.deere.oracledataupdate.*")
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="com.deere.oracledataupdate.dao.springdata")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.deere.oracledataupdate.*")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application-${IafConfigSuffix}.properties" })

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 

public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which spring boot version are you using.

Comment: i am using 1.2.3.RELEASE of spring boot

Comment: Update to the most recent 1.2.6... Earlier versions of the JMS auto configuration relied on the `PlatformTransactionManager` newer versions the specific `JtaTransactionManager` as it (generally) makes sense to have transactions there.

Comment: it worked after changing version to latest release  :)  Thanks Deinum

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the current Spring Boot code we have (`JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration`):

```
@Autowired(required = false)
private JtaTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

So, right now it requires only the bean which is exactly `JtaTransactionManager` by type. I guess both yours are `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

I'm sure that was correct fix to worry only about the `XA` tx-manager for auto-config.

Seems for me you can fix your issue with something like `@Primary` on one of your tx-manager beans.

But... Do you need a JMS Annotation support in your application at all?

Maybe it would be just enough to **exclude** `JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` as well?

If need it anyway, I see only one way to fix it: disable `JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` and configure `@EnableJms` manually, bypassing the tx-manager issue and just don't configure it for the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` as you request.

See `JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` source code for more information.

Comment: Hi Artem, i just changed spring boot version to latest release and it stopped giving that error. before changing version i have tried suggestion you provided like tried excluding JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration but there was no JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class when i was adding this to @SpringBootApplication(exclude={}). it would be good if you let me knw how to configure @EnableJms manually as you mentioned or share an example link.

Comment: 1. Not sure why you don't have `JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` because it is a part of your StackTrace above. 2. Please, refer to the Spring Manual regarding `@EnableJms`: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated